# Prettier: no matching files error on literally empty project

Tags: prettier

I have encountered a really strange behavior of Prettier. I cloned a project from github and tried to run prettier on it using `npx prettier --write .` and got this error:

[image]

I started investigation and was not able to find the cause of the issue. During that I literally deleted all files and almost completely removed everything from the project to the point it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

That didn't help. The funny thing is that I created a simpler project from scratch by myself and everything works fine in that project, even though it is identical to this that I am having trouble with. Can you suggest what it could be? Why am I not able to run `npx prettier --write .` on an almost empty project without any configuration or etc. preventing it from working?

One more note: it seems to work fine when using file extension masks, but fails when running on `.` or `src` or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was an issue with the prettier version.
First project used old `^1.19.1`, and the second fresh one `2.8.3`. When i updated prettier version the problem was fixed.